# Интеграция ЯндексКарты на сайт

Tags: html, yandex-maps-api

При генерации карт на Яндексе, выдается тег script для вставки в html, подскажите как вместить блок карт в отдельный div со своим расположением?

Comment: А в чем собственно проблема? Создаете DIV и помещаете внутрь код который дает вам яндекс

Comment: пробовал - результат такой же как будто вставил script в body

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Kramk , вот Вам пример, который демонстрирует, что при вставке этого скрипта в поток элементов, на странице он преобразуется в карту

[Результат на CodePen](https://codepen.io/hisbvdis/pen/VoQOJr)

```html
<div class="mapTest">
  
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/services/constructor/1.0/js/?um=constructor%3A497eb38dd6fc187fa1150db3c5141c2f79facc21d28d5b83dd769538c31865a5&amp;width=400&amp;height=400&amp;lang=ru_RU&amp;scroll=true"></script>
  
</div>
```